# How to filter data from metaData(Object) from mongoDb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
    let filter = {
      "metaData.transaction_id":body.transaction_id
    }
    let paymentInstance = await AppUserPayment.findOne(filter);
```

Getting null:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60059baeb4295aa81ce51ed0"
    },
    "status": true,
    "_isDeleted": false,
    "metaData": {
        "transaction_id": 1847394
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-01-18T14:31:10.841Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-01-18T14:31:10.841Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

How to filter data from metadata (object) in MongoDB? added code and collection. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: getting null, can't fetch data.{ 'metaData.transaction_id': '1847394' }
null

Comment: remove single quotes from number, because it is in number type in your collection. try `parseInt(body.transaction_id)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should convert type of `body.transaction_id` to number, you can like this :

```
let filter = {
      "metaData.transaction_id": +body.transaction_id
    }
    let paymentInstance = await AppUserPayment.findOne(filter);
```